# using HashSet as underlying storage to replicate a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashset

I was asked a question today to re-implement the dictionary. My solution is to use a HashSet as the storage, and a class to represent the KeyValue pair. In this class, I override the GetHashCode and Equals methods in order to add the KeyValue pair instance to the HashSet.

I then read the source code for C# Dictionary, and found it uses the array for storage, and loop through the array to find the matching keyvalues.

Is my approach correct? What is advantage of current Dictionary implementation in C#? Thanks in advance.

```
public class MyDictionary<K,V>
{
    private class KV
    {
        public K Key {get;set;}
        public V Value {get;set;}

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Key.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object o)
        {
            var obj = ((KV)o).Key;
            return Key.Equals(obj);
        }
    }

    private readonly HashSet<KV> _store = new HashSet<KV>();

    public void Add(K key, V value)
    {
        _store.Add(new KV{Key = key, Value = value});
    }

    public V this[K key]
    {
        get
        {
            KV _kv;
            if (_store.TryGetValue(new KV{Key = key}, out _kv))
            {
                return _kv.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                return default(V);
            }
        }

        set
        {
            this.Add(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The current dictionary _is_ implemented as an hashset. It uses buckets to store the items. If there are multiple items in one bucket a linear search in that bucket is performed.

Comment: The advantage of Dictionary<> is that you don't have to write this code.  It is not better.  Using arrays to implement the collection type is extremely important on modern machines, locality of reference makes the processor happy.  Both HashSet<> and Dictionary<> use them, they have to.

Comment: Internally `HashSet` is implemented in a similar way as `Dictionary`.

Comment: Hmmm.  I'm not sure where I heard this (but I did work at Microsoft for a dozen years), but...  I thought Dictionary started out as a simple collection until some N items was reached.  At that point, it started using a hash table.  The idea is that simple was better and more performant for small dictionaries, but hash tables quickly gained an advantage once N became large enough.

Comment: @HansPassant I think OP was asked to implement it and OP decided to use a hashset but then read the .NET dictionary implementation and it internally uses an array. So the question is why it uses an array. The question is not whether OPs code is better.

Comment: @HansPassant why Dictionary not using HashSet as the internal storage instead of array as HashSet uses array anyway?

Comment: @Flydog57 You're probably thinking of a `switch` statement, which behaves that way.  Or perhaps a comparable data structure from some other language (or third party).

Comment: @Servy: that makes sense.  Then the decision can be made at compile time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you think `HashSet` is implemented?  The code that you're seeing in `Dictionary` is going to look very similar to the code that's internally in `HashSet`.  Both are backed by an array that stores a collection of all of the keyed items that share a hash, it's just that one stores a key and a pair, and one just stores the key on its own.

If you're just asking why the developer for `Dictionary` re-implemented some similar code to what's in a `HashSet` rather than actually using the actual `HashSet` internally, we can only guess.  They naturally *could* have, if they wanted to, in the sense that they can create functionally identical results from the perspective of an outside observer.

Comment: that makes sense. Thought there may be some good reasons not to reuse HashSet to implement Dictionary instead of re-implementing the logic.

Comment: "why the developer for Dictionary re-implemented some similar code to what's in a HashSet rather than actually using the actual HashSet internally" - I guess because of the layer of indirection necessary for either inheritance or building. They didn't want to impose the performance penalty.

Answer (score 1):

The reason to use Dictionary is because it is well written, well tested, is already done, and it works.

Your code has a problem when replacing the value associated with a key that's already been added. The following code:

```
dict["hi"]=10;
dict["hi"]=4;
Console.WriteLine(dict["hi"]);
```

will output `10` with your class. Dictionary will output (correctly) `4`.

As far as the use of arrays, both HashSet and Dictionary use them in their implementations.

HashSet

```
    private int[] m_buckets;
    private HashSet<T>.Slot[] m_slots;
```

Dictionary

```
    private int[] buckets;
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Entry[] entries;
```

HashSet and Dictionary do not loop through their arrays to find the key/value. They use a modulus of the hashcode value to directly index into the bucket array. The value in the bucket array points into the slots or entries array. Then, they loop over the list of keys that had identical hashcodes or colliding hashcodes (two different hashcodes that result in the same value after the modulus is applied). These little collision lists are in the slots or entries arrays, and are typically very small, usually with just a single element.

Why isn't Dictionary just implemented onto HashSet? Because the two classes do two different things. HashSet is geared towards storing a set of unique keys. Dictionary is geared towards storing values associated with unique keys. You tried to use a HashSet to store a value by embedding it in the key (which is an object). But I pointed out why that fails to work. It's because HashSet doesn't entertain the concept of a value. It cares only for the key. So it's not suited to being used as a dictionary. Now, you could use Dictionary to implement a HashSet, but that would be wasteful, as there is code and memory in Dictionary dedicated to handling the values. There are two classes, that are each made to fulfill a specific purpose. They are similar, but not the same

Comment: So if you are asked at an interview to implement a dictionary to test your skills, you would say no because it exists and *The reason to use Dictionary is because it is well written, well tested, is already done, and it works.*? Your answer has valuable info but that sentence ruins the answer.

Comment: @hatchet, so why Dictionary is not reusing the HashSet as the internal storage for entries?

Comment: @CodingYoshi - who said anything about this being related to interviews?

Comment: @hatchet The first sentence from the question is: *I was asked a question today to re-implement the dictionary.* Maybe it was not asked in an interview but maybe it was. The point is the user needs to implement it.

Comment: @CodingYoshi - I guess we would need to find out more about why that question was asked. But if it were an interview question, I doubt an answer built on top of HashSet is what the asker was looking for.

Comment: @hatchet, yes, it was asked in the interview. Why built on top of HashSet is not a valid answer for interview question?

Comment: @Helic - If I asked that in an interview, I would look at a solution built on HashSet as not much better than a solution built on Dictionary. If I asked that, I would really be looking for an actual implementation that used either open or closed hashing, or one of the non-hashing based solutions, and showed a knowledge of how dictionaries actually work. But that's just my personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

> What is advantage of ... us[ing] the array for storage, and loop[ing] through the array to find the matching keyvalues[?]

I can answer this from a Java perspective. I think it's very similar in C#.

The Big O time complexity of a get from a hashset is O(1), while an array is O(n). Naively, one might think the hashset would perform better. But it's not that simple. Computing a hash code is relatively expensive, and each class provides its own hashing algorithm, so the run time and quality of hash distribution can vary widely. (It is inefficient but perfectly legal for a class to return the same hash for every object. Hash based collections storing such objects will degenerate to array performance.)

The upshot of all this is that despite the theoretical performance difference, it turns out that for small collections, which are the vast majority of collections in a typical program, iterating over an array is faster than computing a hash. Google introduced an array based map as an alternative to hashmap in their Android API, and they suggest that the array based version performs better for collections up to around 10 to 100 elements. The uncertain range is because, as I mentioned, the cost of hashing varies.

Bottom line... if performance matters, forget Big O and trust your benchmarks.

Comment: I think it is not avoidable to generate hashcode for both Dictionary and HashSet. So that cost still exists.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your implementation is that a HashSet only stores a single entry for the specified key, in your case the hash value. So if the caller wants to add two entries to your dictionary that happen to have the same hash value then only the first is stored, the second is ignored.

A dictionary is typically implemented as a list of entries that match the hash value, that way you can have multiple entries with the same hash value. This does make it more complicated because when adding/removing/looking up you need to handle the list.

Comment: The dictionary needs to satisfy both same hashvalue and equals if a collision on the hash value. I could have implemented it better. But my question really is why Dictionary not using HashSet as the internal storage given the features already provided by the HashSet class, why it uses array?